# How can I print session values in different places in the code?

Tags: php, session-variables

I have problem in printing the values of session when I put the print statement directly after the session_start() function it prints but if I put it lower in the code it does not print !

```
<?php  session_start();print_r($_SESSION);
?>
<? include("db1.php");
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('blog/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title><? print_r($_SESSION['title']);?></title>
</head>
```

Comment: between <body> and </body> :-)

Comment: `<title><?php echo $_SESSION['title']; ?></title>`

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have short tags enabled you will need to keep using `<?php` and `?>` all through your code.

```
<head>
    <title><?php print_r($_SESSION['title']);?></title>
</head>
```

Edit: See this for further information on [short tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)

Edit Two: Can you verify the output of the `print_r()`? Are you certain that the element is called `'title'`?

Edit Three:
Seeing as I am about to head off to bed, here is a workaround at least:

```
<?php  
    session_start();
    print_r($_SESSION);
    // As it works here...
    $myTitle=$_SESSION['title'];
?>

<head>
    <title><?php echo $title;?></title>
</head>
```

Comment: @Amer Enaya `<? ?>` are called short tags

Comment: @AmerEnaya Have you tried Aspirin's suggestion of echoing it out?

Comment: @AmerEnaya Can you verify the output of the print_r()? Are you certain that the element is called 'title'?

Comment: yes I have the element title and when I print $_SESSION['title'] directly after I call session_start(); it prints but in the body or head section it does not print

Comment: @AmerEnaya Not sure and about to go to bed, but I gave you a work-around that should do the trick, although it is quick and dirty...

Answer (score 0):

What is printed out instead of the $_SESSION variable content? What if you use var_dump($_SESSION);? why are you using print_r to print a title tag? why not to use (if you have to use session as a container) echo $_SESSION['title']; ?

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. I understand that you don't have the rep yet to post comments but for future ref, this type of answer will get moved or deleted.

Comment: @AmerEnaya what about hte other questions?

Comment: @Fluffeh my mistake... sorry. won't delete it tho as the original poster used it to answer me.

Comment: @MiroslavHudak Yup, I saw your rep and assumed it was so.